# Shared libs load offsets missing in core dump

Tags: c++, gdb, mips, coredump, openwrt

I loaded a core dump from a MIPS openwrt process in cross-gdb for that platform. The stack trace isn't helpful and I'm trying to figure out where it crashed from the pointers on the stack:

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x77ce2810 in ?? ()
(gdb) set sysroot rootfs/
Loaded symbols for rootfs/lib/libc.so.0

[...more lines while loading symbols...]

(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libssp.so.0
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libdl.so.0
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libpthread.so.0
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libm.so.0
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libc.so.0
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
0x77bea200  0x77c70de0  Yes (*)     rootfs/lib/libbdnc.so
                        No          /usr/lib/libssl.so
                        No          /usr/lib/libcrypto.so
                        Yes (*)     rootfs/usr/lib/libz.so
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Libbdnc is the only one for which I see the load address. It's loaded via dlopen(). The rest are linked into the executable via -l. They are all present in rootfs/ but apparently not picked up by `set sysroot`.

The top of the stack looks like this:

```
(gdb) x/50a $sp    
0x76fafe88: 0x427370 <stderr>   0x77d04000  0x77df70b4  0x77cf4000
0x76fafe98: 0x0 0x1 0x77e9f000  0x427370 <stderr>
0x76fafea8: 0x77d033a0  0x77df70b4  0x77df70c4  0x420000
0x76faffb8: 0x0 0x0 0x77e33160  0x0
0x76faffc8: 0x0 0x40ee98 <bdnc_init+176>    0x0 0x0
```

My question is how can I figure out what the other pointers are, and whether failure to determine load addresses for most of the libs is why the stack values don't resolve to symbols.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is ...

You'll likely get better result if you set `sysroot` before loading core. That is:

```
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) set sysroot rootfs/
(gdb) core ./core
```